# Folder naming in MVC3 - /ActionFilters or /Filters or?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I recently asked about the location of Action Filters in MVC. Some people suggested at the same level as the controllers folder, some suggested below and others suggested at the project level. Now I realize the project level may be best as I use Areas and have multiple controller folders.

The suggestion was to create a folder called /Filters.  I know of Action Filters but are there any other kind of filters in MVC?

What would be best.

- Folder called Filters
- Folder called ActionFilters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use any name Filters or ActionFilters. If we need to create ActionFilers for several purposes, we can add these all ActionFilers in the same folder.

See the CodePlex page about [Creating a common library with ASP.NET MVC Action Filters](http://mvcactionfilter.codeplex.com/), where you can find some links about practices of using action filters in a project.

Also see a tutorial for [ActionFilter in ASP.Net](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/understanding-action-filters-cs)